# Do all matter emits radiation at all wavelengths?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, radiation, thermal-radiation, photon-emission

Does all matter emit radiation at all wavelengths? Do gasses also emit radiation at all wavelengths since they have a specific emission spectrum? Shouldn't they only emit radiation according to their emission spectrum?

Furthermore, how can all matter emit radiation at all wavelengths when they have different emission spectrums and energy levels?

**UPDATE:** Do humans for example emit gamma rays if we were to follow the blackbody radiation curve?

Comment: For your second question see [What are the various physical mechanisms for energy transfer to the photon during blackbody emission?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/59213/what-are-the-various-physical-mechanisms-for-energy-transfer-to-the-photon-durin).

Comment: Both links do answer my question to a certain extent but I am still wondering whether or not everything (both gases, solids, and liquids) emits radiation at all wavelengths.

Comment: I think the reason for that is that you have asked several questions in one; as for the question in the update you might want to look at [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/635495/how-does-plancks-curve-solve-the-ultraviolet-catastrophe).

Comment: *Do humans for example emit gamma rays?* When $f$ is the frequency of a low-energy gamma ray and $T$ is the temperature of a human body, the Boltzmann factor $e^{-hf/kT}$ is around $10^{-20,170,498}$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a comment that needs a plot.

Black body radiation curves are fitted with  the [Planck formula](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mod6.html) and are used for the very hot radiations from cosmological objects, that is why it is hard to find room temperature plots. I found it by googling  "black body radiation at 100C" which gave me  a lot of high temperature curves, and also the following curve that shows the wavelengths related to the temperature of the body radiation at low temperatures.

[image: black bodye]

0 kelvin is -273.15 C.

The high frequencies of gamma rays are on the left of this plot, and are nonexistent for the low temperature curves. If you go to the trouble of translating the scale to Herz.
Thus the answer to:

> Do humans for example emit gamma rays if we were to follow the blackbody radiation curve?

is no, it cannot  happen.